# PHP Changed Domain, how to remove old Session Cookies

Tags: php

Title is pretty self explanatory. I am entirely new to PHO and am working on a site that was moved to a new domain, but some users still have old session cookies associated with the old domain. I have tried to remove the old cookie by setting the expiry data but the old cookie seems unchanged and the new one seems to be removed, as I do not successfully login. Could anyone possibly advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ultimate solution to this issue ending up being just creating a new cookie at login and letting the old cookie expire, despite it being counterintuitive to the final design.